# Image is below other elements

Tags: html, css, web

I have a problem with my website. I have a small image in my website and it is located lower than other **body** elements. Thank you for helping.

```
  <header style="position:fixed"class="container-fluid header a">

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-1"><a href="#top"><img src="http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/img-thing?.out=jpg&size=l&tid=46293357"style="max-width:90px"class="img-responsive"></a></div>

 <div class="col-xs-6, col-xs-offset-9"style="padding-top:2%">
  <a href="#scr"><button class="btn btn-primary button">ABOUT</button></a>
  <a href="#scr"><button class="btn btn-primary button">PORTFOLIO</button></a>
  <a href="#scr"><button class="btn btn-primary button">CONTACT</button></a>

   </div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
<body style="padding-top:20%; background-color:yellow;">
<p class="centered">First website of Terlan Ismayilsoy</p>
 <div class="row">
 <div>
 <div class="col-xs-1 hr">

     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-1"style="padding-top:2%;margin-right:2%"><h1><b>&lt;/&gt;</b></h1></div>
   </div>

   <div>
 <img src="https://www.brandeps.com/logo-download/F/Flag-map-of-Azerbaijan-01.png" class="img-responsive little "class="pull-right  pull-up">
   </div>

 </div>


 </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly are you trying to do? What things have you already tried that haven't worked?

Comment: the image is the last element in your body - what else do you expect?

Comment: You should not place divds in the header tag, all the content of your website should be in the body tag, the header tag should have metatags and links to css/scripts